# TYPO3 - Is there an (easy) way to view the content of static templates?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-extensions

In TYPO3 you often need to include "Static Templates" from an extension to make the extension work.

[image: image from typo3 documentation]

However, it seems there is no way in TYPO3 backend to see what typoscript is actually inside these static templates.

My question is: is there a way to view the contents of these static templates without browsing the extension's sources codes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "Template" module is only there for TypoScript Templates (1). Within the module you can select "Template Analyzer" from the function menu (2).
Within this module you can select the static template, e.g. of form extension (3). This will display constants and setup (4).

When using a composer setup, you might need to require [typo3/cms-tstemplate](https://packagist.org/packages/typo3/cms-tstemplate).

[image: Backend module displaying static template content]

Comment: Thank you, this helps. There is no way to view static templates in typo3 backend without including them first, correct? I will create an invisible dummy page then just to include  every available static template there so i can view them. Is this an advisable way to go?

Comment: What's the reason not to have a look on filesystem level?

I'm not aware of an native way from TYPO3 backend to see them without your approach.

What's your use case anyway, to see all contents of all static templates?

Comment: I want all static typoscripts in one place, to get good quick overview of what is going on.
Some extensions are in `typo3conf/ext` others are in `typo3/sysext` (inside a docker container in my case). I was wondering why some extensions work without the static TS included, some do not. 
I learned now: some extensions just have auto generated static TS files (made with Extension Builder probably) .. but the TS seems to never get used by the extension.