# How to update with femanager (TYPO3)?

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-9.x, typo3-extensions

I'm working on a project and my task is : set up a page to edit my user account information. For this, I have to use the TYPO3 extension femanager.

I installed the extension and put the plugin on my page. I have 4 fields that are displayed (photo, phone numbers and email). But when i submit my form, I have this error :

> Argument 2 passed to
> In2code\Femanager\Utility\FrontendUtility::forceValues() must be of
> the type array, null given, called in
> /home/dev/rta/htdocs/typo3conf/ext/femanager/Classes/Controller/EditController.php
> on line 69

I tried to look for someone with a similar problem on the Internet but couldn't find anything. I looked at the code, but since it's the base extension code, I don't think that's where the problem comes from. The users are stored in the **fe_users** table in my database and the fields pre-fill nicely with my existing data.

I just learned TYPO3 3 weeks ago so I have a lot of gaps and I'm not very familiar with it yet.

If it can help, here is my EditController.php (lines 66 to 79) :

```php
public function updateAction(User $user)
    {
        $this->redirectIfDirtyObject($user);
        $user = FrontendUtility::forceValues($user, $this->config['edit.']['forceValues.']['beforeAnyConfirmation.']);
        $this->emailForUsername($user);
        UserUtility::convertPassword($user, $this->settings['edit']['misc']['passwordSave']);
        $this->signalSlotDispatcher->dispatch(__CLASS__, __FUNCTION__ . 'BeforePersist', [$user, $this]);
        if (!empty($this->settings['edit']['confirmByAdmin'])) {
            $this->updateRequest($user);
        } else {
            $this->updateAllConfirmed($user);
        }
        $this->redirect('edit');
    }
```

And here is my FrontendUtility class (used in my EditController at line 69) :

```php
public static function forceValues(User $user, array $settings)
    {
        foreach ((array)$settings as $field => $config) {
            $config = null;
            if (stristr($field, '.')) {
                continue;
            }
            // value to set
            $value = self::getContentObject()->cObjGetSingle($settings[$field], $settings[$field . '.']);
            if ($field === 'usergroup') {
                // need objectstorage for usergroup field
                $user->removeAllUsergroups();
                $values = GeneralUtility::trimExplode(',', $value, true);
                $userGroupRepository = self::getUserGroupRepository();

                foreach ($values as $usergroupUid) {
                    /** @var UserGroup $usergroup */
                    $usergroup = $userGroupRepository->findByUid($usergroupUid);
                    $user->addUsergroup($usergroup);
                }
            } else {
                // set value
                if (method_exists($user, 'set' . ucfirst($field))) {
                    $user->{'set' . ucfirst($field)}($value);
                }
            }
        }
        return $user;
    }
```

If anyone has an idea, I'm interested!

*PS : I use TYPO3 v9.5.8*

Comment: As we can see the second argument tries to read from static TS config, did you include all required TSes from this ext at the page level and made all required changes in these configs?

Comment: @biesior Well, i have a message "No TypoScript found. Did you already include the static Template?" so I think it's related but I can't figure out what I might have forgotten. I've just install the ext via the extension manager and put the plugin on my page. I can't access to the configuration in the extension manager, I don't know if it's necessary or not.

Comment: "*I have a message "No TypoScript found*" that's what I'm talking about, you need to go to module Web > Templates > page with your template > info/modify > edit the whole record > includes tab and make sure that femanager TS is added on tle left pane

Comment: BTW this is very common mistake in TYPO3, please search the net, most probably you'll find some articles with screenshots and more details.like [in the docs of the other ext](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/frsupersized/stable/Administration/IncludeStaticTemplate(optional)/Index.html) or [even here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56930684/1066240)